# Adding HTTP cache to slim 3

Tags: php, http-caching, slim-3

I have a route :

```
$app->get('/api/home',['\App\Controllers\HomepageController','getAllCards']);
```

In my App.php file, I have registered the service provider as:

```
$dependencies = [ 'cache' => function(Container $container) {
                   return new \Slim\HttpCache\CacheProvider();
                   },
                ];
```

In my index.php file:

```
$app = new \App\App;
$container = $app->getContainer();
$app->add(new \Slim\HttpCache\Cache('public', 86400));
```

How do I add the cache with headers like CacheControl,Etag,expires,etc in the above route?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/caching.html) page.

Comment: I already read the documentation and implied as given in the docs. When there was no change in the header at client-side, I turned up to SO  @JeroenHeier